# PHP fsockopen ldap domain search

Tags: php, ldap, fsockopen

**Context:** 
I am using a domain name address to try and check the connections to a domain controller but not all domain controllers are accessible from the server running the PHP. So I am using a loop to see if a domain controller is there to respond with using fsockopen.

Domain.ad points to 15 possible domain controllers. server.domain.ad, server2.domain.ad, etc

```
...
$i = 0;
do
{
    $fp = fsockopen("domain.ad", 389, $errno, $errstr, 1);
    $i++;
}
while(!$fp && $i < 15);
...
//$ip = $fp->getAddress(); or something like that.
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to find out from the fsockopen connection of what IP address / domain controller it was successful to connect with to be used later in the code to complete the LDAP bind with? Or is there a better way to do this without using 1 domain controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution for iterating through the domain controllers.

```
$ipDomain = dns_get_record("domain.ad", DNS_A);
$i = 0;
do
{
    $fp = fsockopen($ipDomain[$i]['ip'], 389, $errno, $errstr, 1);
    if(!$fp)
    {
        $i++;
        if($i >= sizeof($ipDomain))
        {
            break;
            //die();
        }
    }
}
while(!$fp);
...
ldap_connect($ipDomain[$i]['ip']);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve there. `fsockopen` tries to open a connection to the given server on the given port. You are also setting a timeout. But you do that in a loop. So you try to open a connection 15 times in a row and increase the timeout to the server by one second on each run. But from what I read there are multiple domain-controllers available. Depending on the network-setup the first one available should react and act as "your" endpoint. You as a user of that system should not need to check which one you can reach and which one you can't. You should just get a handle back when you do an `ldap_connect('ldap://domain.ad:389);`.

Alternatively you can do a DNS-Query for the domain-controller via `gethostbyname('domain.ad')` which will give you the IP-address of the given host. But as I said, there should not be a need for that when your network is properly maintained.

When you have **more than one servername** you can use them in a space-delimited list as parameter to `ldap_connect`like this:

```
ldap_connect('ldap://domain.ad:389 ldap://domain2.ad:389 ldaps://domain.ad:123');
```

That should connect to the first available server.

Though you will have to beware one issue: `ldap_connect` does **not** connect! The connection is usually first opened on `ldap_bind`! So connection issues will **not** surface on the `ldap_connect`. Should you get a `false` back there that simply means the provided parameter does not meet the expectations! That's why I'm usually first using `fsockopen` to check whether the server is available should that be an issue so I can fail fast.

Comment: Does "domain.ad" have 15 CNAMEs or 15 A-records? The DNS should only return those servers that are accessible from your machine. Alternatively do a DNS-query to find all A-records and loop over them to find an accessible one.

Comment: That is actually want i did yesterday afternoon.